# How to Parse(get the value) nested json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587f5455da1da85d2bd01fc5"),
    "totalTime" : 0,
    "lastUpdatedBy" : ObjectId("57906bf8f4add282195d0a88"),
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("57906bf8f4add282195d0a88"),
    "workSpaceId" : ObjectId("57906c24f4add282195d0a8a"),
    "locationId" : ObjectId("5790629c841f1a9913b12104"),
    "projectId" : ObjectId("57906d33f4add282195d0aa2"),
    "title" : "asdf asdfasdf",
    "subTitles" : [
        {
            "childrensTitle" : "fffffffffffff",
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("57906bf8f4add282195d0a88"),
            "lastUpdatedBy" : ObjectId("57906bf8f4add282195d0a88"),
            "totalTime" : 0,
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-18T11:41:32.974Z"),
            "subTitles" : [
                {
                    "childrensTitle" : "Ufffffff",
                    "createdBy" : ObjectId("57906bf8f4add282195d0a88"),
                    "lastUpdatedBy" : ObjectId("57906ce1f4add282195d0a96"),
                    "totalTime" : 0,
                    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-18T11:41:37.151Z"),
                    "subTitles" : [
                        {
                            "childrensTitle" : "date n time",
                            "createdBy" : ObjectId("57906bf8f4add282195d0a88"),
                            "lastUpdatedBy" : ObjectId("57906bf8f4add282195d0a88"),
                            "totalTime" : 0,
                            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-18T11:41:40.716Z"),
                            "subTitles" : [ ],
                            "_id" : ObjectId("587f5474da1da85d2bd01fcb")
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("587f5471da1da85d2bd01fca")
                }
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("587f546cda1da85d2bd01fc9")
        }
    ],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-18T11:41:09.301Z"),
    "__v" : 3
}
```

I am trying to print `totalTime` of each level but I am only able to print it up to 2 layers… after that it is `undefined`. For example:

```
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[req.body.index].subTitles[req.body.index].subTitles[req.body.index].totalTime) // undefined
```

Comment: Your json is not valid

Comment: you can say nested/embed array of same type(rescursive) !! @ricky

Comment: Please tell me where i am wrong :(

Comment: `ObjectId("587f5455da1da85d2bd01fc5")` this is valid in MongoDB but if you talk about JSON, It's invalid data type. It should be like `"587f5455da1da85d2bd01fc5"`

Comment: yes you are right its mongodb one!!

Comment: You can validate your JSON data [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This is not JSON. This is a JavaScript representation of BSON from MongoDB, which just happens to use unnecessarily quoted object keys.

You would need to define `ISODate()` and `ObjectId()` functions (that you can take from Mongo driver or Mongoose) and use them to parse the calls to those functions. Otherwise you will get errors because those functions are undefined.

And you cannot use `JSON.parse()` to parse it because this is not JSON.

### Update

When you access:

```
mainTitle[0].subTitles[req.body.index].subTitles[req.body.index].subTitles[req.body.index].totalTime
```

I would simplify it as:

```
var i = req.body.index;
mainTitle[0].subTitles[i].subTitles[i].subTitles[i].totalTime
```

but that's just for readability.

I would test in one nesting level at a time:

```
var i = req.body.index;
console.log(i);
console.log(mainTitle);
console.log(mainTitle[0]);
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles);
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i]);
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i].subTitles);
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i].subTitles[i]);
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i].subTitles[i].subTitles);
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i].subTitles[i].subTitles[i]);
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i].subTitles[i].subTitles[i].totalTime);
```

Not pretty but sometimes it's a best way to narrow down the problem.

### Modules that can help

To access deep structures you can use:

- [hoek.reach](https://github.com/hapijs/hoek/blob/master/API.md#reachobj-chain-options)
- [hoek.reachTemplate](https://github.com/hapijs/hoek/blob/master/API.md#reachtemplateobj-template-options)
- [lodash.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get)
- [property-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/property-path)

Comment: Thank You all  for your valuable suggestions !!

Comment: i am not getting any error  !! i just could not console "totalTime" field.....but i am able to console "childrensTitle" field please give any suggestions on that.  i am using #MeanStack framework

Comment: @TushBedva See my updated answer for more suggestions.

Comment: i have tried this var i = req.body.index;
console.log(i); 
console.log(mainTitle); 
console.log(mainTitle[0]); 
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles); 
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i]); 
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i].subTitles); 
console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i].subTitles[i]);           yes i did this too but i am able get up to  console.log(mainTitle[0].subTitles[i].subTitles[i]); (2 layers) .... after that it is consoling undefined if i keep totalTime. but if i dont keep totalTime it is coming !!

Comment: @TushBedva The answer is written by rsp, not by me.